# How does Ruby Test:Unit locate test classes in a deep nested folder?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-test

How does Ruby Test:Unit locate test classes in a deep nested folder?  I am a Java developer and I understand how JUnit and TestNG can scan folders with a defined filter to locate tests.

I am wondering if someone can explain to me how Ruby can locate test classes with a similar method, preferrably using some kind of filename filter??

Say, for example, I have a directory structure like so; then how could Ruby Test::Unit test runner locate only the tests ending with the letter 'b'??

```
project
  -main
  -tests
    -group1
      -test1a.rb
      -test1b.rb
    -group2
      -test2a.rb
      -test2b.rb
    -group3
      -test3a.rb
      -test3b.rb
    -group4
      -test4a.rb
      -test4b.rb
```

Links to documentation are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out, unless someone else comes up with a better answer, it seems that the [Rake tool has this capability](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests).